# Create a PHP Class Outline

Tags: php, architecture, object, class-design, outline

I am looking for a function or class that can effectively outline a class:

```
class MyClass{

  /*
  * Perhaps include the function comments
  * in the function.
  */
  function mainFunction(){
    //Does Something
  } 

  function functionWithArgs($arg1,$arg2=false){
    //Does Something
    //The function I want will give e the arguments w/default values
  }

}
```

Is there a function or library in existence that can give me some kind of access to the information about this class, or even the file.

ex.

`get_file_outline('fileWithAboveClass.php');`

or

`get_class_outline('MyClass');`

Does anybody know of either, or know a way of easily writing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the PHP [Reflection API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php)

```
//use the ReflectionClass to find out about MyClass
$classInfo = new ReflectionClass('MyClass'); 

//then you can find out pretty much anything you want to know...
$methods = $classInfo->getMethods(); 
var_dump($methods);

//you can even extract your comments, e.g.
$comment=$classInfo->getMethod('mainFunction')->getDocComment();
```

Note that for the comment extraction to work, they have to be formatted like PHPDoc / Doxygen comments, and begin with an opening `/**`

Comment: That is very helpful, Thanks! Is there any way to get the function arguments?

Comment: yes, once you've got the ReflectionMethod object for the method, you can obtain all sorts of info, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php

Comment: Yes, I just saw that.  Thanks a million, you saved me a ton of time :)

Answer (score 0):

There's also a command line option available for inspecting functions and classes.

```
$ php --rc DateTime
```

will give you all the details about the DateTime-class, while

```
$ php --rf in_array
```

will give you the arguments of the "in_array" function.

If you're using the Terminal when coding it can be quite handy to use instead of looking it up in the PHP Manual all the time ;)